# List Box in Ruby Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

I've been using Ruby Shoes for the past week or so, trying to get a nice introduction to it. I just started using the list_box but I can't figure out how to code it out so that when a specific choice in a listbox is chosen, something else happens- I couldn't really understand what the manual was trying to do

```
x=1
list_box :items => ["Repair", "Request"]
```

In this case, I'd like for `x` to equal 1 when `repair` is chosen and equal 2 when `request` is chosen. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Found on [this page](http://shoesrb.com/manual/ListBox.html).

You can do stuff like

```
Shoes.app do
  para "Choose a fruit:"
  list_box :items => ["Grapes", "Pears", "Apricots"],
           :width => 120,
           :choose => "Apricots" do |list|
    @fruit.text = list.text
  end
  @fruit = para "No fruit selected"
end
```

So, you could inspect the `list` object and see what variables you can access and then do what you want based on the chosen option.